# How do I convert a Pandas dataframe to a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pytorch

How do I train a simple neural network with PyTorch on a pandas dataframe `df`?

The column `df["Target"]` is the target (e.g. labels) of the network. This doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

target = pd.DataFrame(df['Target'])
train = data_utils.TensorDataset(df, target)
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Comment: **Issue:** your features (`df`) also contains the target variable (`df['Target']`) (i.e. your network is 'cheating', since it can see the results as input)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I'm referring to the question in the title as you haven't really specified anything else in the text, so just converting the DataFrame into a PyTorch tensor.

Without information about your data, I'm just taking float values as example targets here.

**Convert Pandas dataframe to PyTorch tensor?**

```py
import pandas as pd
import torch
import random

# creating dummy targets (float values)
targets_data = [random.random() for i in range(10)]

# creating DataFrame from targets_data
targets_df = pd.DataFrame(data=targets_data)
targets_df.columns = ['targets']

# creating tensor from targets_df 
torch_tensor = torch.tensor(targets_df['targets'].values)

# printing out result
print(torch_tensor)
```

**Output:**

```
tensor([ 0.5827,  0.5881,  0.1543,  0.6815,  0.9400,  0.8683,  0.4289,
         0.5940,  0.6438,  0.7514], dtype=torch.float64)
```

*Tested with Pytorch 0.4.0.*

I hope this helps, if you have any further questions - just ask. :)

Comment: Using your code i wrote this:
`train_target = torch.tensor(train['Target'].values)
train = torch.tensor(train.drop('Target', axis = 1).values)
train_tensor = data_utils.TensorDataset(train, train_target)
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(dataset = train_tensor, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True)`

Running the neural net model i get this error:
`RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.FloaTtensor but found type torch.DoubleTensor for argument #4 'mat1'`

Comment: What PyTorch version version are you using? Version `0.3.1.` is very different from version `0.4.0.` .

Comment: I'm using pytorch 0.4.0, tested with `print(torch.__version__)`

Comment: How does your DataFrame look like? Best would be to update your question, otherwise it gonna be difficult to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Just for the records, on terminology: you are not converting a pandas DataFrame, rather a Pandas series (which you first coerce to array applying `.values`).

Comment: Tensors are multidimensional (otherwise we call them vectors and matrices). Can you please show construction of a 3D torch tensor from a column (series) of a DataFrame?

Answer (score 33):

Maybe try this to see if it can fix your problem(based on your sample code)?

```
train_target = torch.tensor(train['Target'].values.astype(np.float32))
train = torch.tensor(train.drop('Target', axis = 1).values.astype(np.float32)) 
train_tensor = data_utils.TensorDataset(train, train_target) 
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(dataset = train_tensor, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use below functions to convert any dataframe or pandas series to a pytorch tensor

```py
import pandas as pd
import torch

# determine the supported device
def get_device():
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = torch.device('cuda:0')
    else:
        device = torch.device('cpu') # don't have GPU 
    return device

# convert a df to tensor to be used in pytorch
def df_to_tensor(df):
    device = get_device()
    return torch.from_numpy(df.values).float().to(device)

df_tensor = df_to_tensor(df)
series_tensor = df_to_tensor(series)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your code but I'm receiving the following error `name 'series' is not defined`.

Comment: @Luis: This is the pandas series you want to convert. Replace it with yours.

Answer (score 12):

You can pass the [`df.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) attribute (a numpy array) to the Dataset constructor directly:

```py
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

# Creating np arrays
target = df['Target'].values
features = df.drop('Target', axis=1).values

# Passing to DataLoader
train = data_utils.TensorDataset(features, target)
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
```

---

**Note:** Your features (`df`) also contains the target variable (`df['Target']`) i.e. your network is 'cheating', since it can see the targets in the input. You need to remove this column from the set of features.

Answer (score 7):

Simply convert the `pandas dataframe -> numpy array -> pytorch tensor`. An example of this is described below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
target = pd.DataFrame(df['target'])
del df['target']
train = data_utils.TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(np.array(df)), torch.Tensor(np.array(target)))
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size = 10, shuffle = True)
```

Hopefully, this will help you to create your own datasets using pytorch (Compatible with the latest version of pytorch).

Answer (score 5):

```
#This works for me

target = torch.tensor(df['Targets'].values)
features = torch.tensor(df.drop('Targets', axis = 1).values)

train = data_utils.TensorDataset(features, target)
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: hello and thanks for your contribution ! any difference with the answer from @iacob ?

Comment: Hi, I had to convert target and features to torch.tensor first.

Answer (score 2):

To convert dataframe to pytorch tensor:
[you can use this to tackle any df to convert it into pytorch tensor]

steps:

- convert df to numpy using df.to_numpy() or df.to_numpy().astype(np.float32) to change the datatype of each numpy array to float32
- convert the numpy to tensor using torch.from_numpy(df) method

example:

```
tensor_ = torch.from_numpy(df.to_numpy().astype(np.float32))
```