# convert Dataframe or list to Tensor using PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor, pcap

I have 25GB .pcap files and want to send the packet bytes to CNN but converting the .pcaps file to CSV makes a large file. I know how to read packets from .pcap files and make a Dataframe or list, is there any way to convert this to PyTorch format? and make train and Test data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas dataframe to PyTorch tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307707/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-pytorch-tensor)

Answer (score 1):

Use the tensor constructor on the dataframe values :

```
torch.tensor(dataframe.values)
```

This will create a tensor then do required pre-processing which is required by your model