# Pandas data to pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I am trying to covert a pandas data frame into a pytorch tensor in order to run a LSTM model, but I keep getting the following error stating that there is value error and unable to determine the shape of the object type 'series'. It then refers to the following code:

```
class MicroESDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, sequences):
        self.sequences = sequences

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sequences)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sequence, label = self.sequences[idx]
        return dict (
            sequence=torch.Tensor(sequence.to_numpy()),
            label = torch.tensor(label).float ()
        )
```

Am I missing something completely obvious? Thanks

Here is the exact error message and traceback:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent       call last)
    <ipython-input-46-fb5c7eb803e1> in <module>()
----> 1 for item in data_module.train_dataloader():
  2   print(item["sequence"].shape)
  3   print(item["label"].shape)
  4   # print(item["label"])
  5   break

    3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py in reraise(self)
427             # have message field
428             raise self.exc_type(message=msg)
--> 429         raise self.exc_type(msg)
  430 
  431 

  ValueError: Caught ValueError in DataLoader worker process 0.
 Original Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 202, in _worker_loop
data = fetcher.fetch(index)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
File "<ipython-input-30-36c44aae196d>", line 13, in __getitem__
label = torch.tensor(label).float()
```

ValueError: could not determine the shape of object type 'Series'

Comment: Please, provide the exact error message and the complete traceback.

Comment: I added the exact error message and traceback in the OP.

Comment: Looks like `label` is a Series object and Tensorflow doesn't know what to do with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas dataframe to PyTorch tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307707/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-pytorch-tensor)

Comment: Please debug with `dataloader`s `num_workers=0` argument passed.

Answer (score 0):

### 2 columns

First of all, `idx` in `Dataset` should refer to row inside `pd.DataFrame`.

Method to get row from it is `df.iloc[idx]` instead of `[idx]` (which would get the column specified by the index, which is probably not you want, if it is you should transpose your data).

Given that, we can do this (dummy `pd.DataFrame` with only `2` columns, **see code comments**):

```
import pandas as pd
import torch


class MicroESDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        # Dummy sequences dataframe
        self.sequences = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2], "col2": [3, 4]})

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sequences)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sequence, label = self.sequences.iloc[idx]
        return dict(
            # torch.tensor infers dtype, torch.Tensor is always float
            sequence=torch.tensor(sequence),
            label=torch.tensor(label).float(),
        )


dataset = MicroESDataset()
print(dataset[0])
```

### More columns

If you have more columns (assuming as `series` probably refers to multiple values) you have to:

- get the row first
- slice by appropriate columns

Given the above one could do (in this case `4` columns, one last being label, **see code comments**):

```
class MicroESDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        # Dummy sequences dataframe
        self.sequences = pd.DataFrame(
            {"col1": [1, 2], "col2": [3, 4], "col3": [5, 6], "col4": [7, 8]}
        )

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sequences)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # No magic unpacking here!
        row = self.sequences.iloc[idx]
        # Now only columns are left and we can slice with the indices
        # One could also slice using : "col3", but I think this is better in ur case
        sequence, label = row.iloc[:-1], row.iloc[-1]
        return dict(
            sequence=torch.tensor(sequence),
            label=torch.tensor(label).float(),
        )


dataset = MicroESDataset()
print(dataset[0])
```