# convert a adjacency matrix into the torch_geometric.data.Data format using python or R

Tags: python, r, graph, adjacency-matrix, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to convert a adjacency matrix into the torch_geometric.data.Data format. I am able to edge index list using csr_matrix.

I also wonder what I should put for x: Node feature matrix with shape [num_nodes, num_node_features], whether this should be the matrix of the edge weights? It would great to have some clarity on what the node feature columns relate to; an practical or theoretical example with a theoretical application would be great.

Help would be appreciated.

```
import torch

# creating tensor from targets_df 
torch_tensor = torch.tensor(adjacencyMat_df.iloc[: , 1:].values) #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307707/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-pytorch-tensor
torch_tensor
```

[image]

```
import scipy.sparse as scpy

A=scpy.csr_matrix(torch_tensor)
print(A)

data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index)
```

Comment: It is as I originally thought. It involves potentially the 90 degree rotation of the selected features, with each sample result along the columns. Then each row represents a single node.

Answer (score 0):

It is as I originally thought. It involves potentially the 90 degree rotation of the selected features, with each sample result along the columns. Then each row represents a single node.

Answer (score 0):

I don' know what you mean by "torch geometric Data" but in PyG you can either use the dense matrix format to store Adjacency matrix data or the sparse format containing only available connections.
Also node features is something other than "edge weights", To understand it better you can look into both edge features and node features separately, meaning that according to your own specific learning task you are going to take out, these paramteres can have different meanings, for example node_features can be a list of atoms used in a molecular dataset, or edge_features can be traffic delays in a road map dataset